# Answering the homework questions

Tags: discussion, homework

As we all know that a lot of homework questions are posted on Stack Overflow. Few just post the question as such without even trying and few genuinely try something and post a specific problem. In the case of second scenario, we should help the OP as the OP has tried his homework and is genuinely stuck somewhere.

My question here is, to what extent are we supposed to help the OP?

Let's consider a scenario. The OP is supposed to do something with `arrays` and `for` loops to remove duplicate elements and the OP seems to be getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for some reason. There is a constraint that the OP can't use `java.util` classes as its not allowed. But when the OP posts a question here, there are many answers which suggest the OP to use a `Set`. Agreed that using a `Set` solves the problem in no time, and its the best solution for this kind of problem, but shouldn't we actually address the OPs actual problem of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and try to help fix that, instead of just asking the OP to use a `Set`.

Isn't that the challenge to try to solve the problem with the given constraints in place? By removing that constraint out, we are not trying to help the OP at all. There have been so many situations where the easiest solutions are of no use, as the OP can't use them due to some constraints. What should be done in such a scenario? Just ask the OP to use a `Set` and not actually help the OP fix his `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` problem.

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19394824/2024761) which has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19394915/2024761) posted by me (now deleted). If you have a look at the comments section, the last comment of the downvoter was the one which prompted me to post this question. For people who can't see the deleted post, here an excerpt from that comment

*If it's HW and he's not allowed to use Set - that's his problem, SO was not meant to help people with their homework*.

I would love to know what others feel about this?! Because I've seen people giving different solutions to the OP, if it was a post by someone working in a project(and not a homework question), having certain constraints on the usage of certain libraries.

Comment: Frankly, the real discussion should be about answering questions which come with constraints, of which homework questions are just a subset. Any "professional's" question which has some sort of constraint imposed does not automatically get ridiculed/closed. The same should extend to homework questions.

Comment: @AsheeshR - Actually non-homework questions with constraints are given solutions considering the constraints. Its just that when people see a homework question, they tend to neglect those constraints. Its kind of like a biased thing. I've seen that happen a lot of times.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That question doesn't appear to address question constraints.

Comment: Constraints should always be honored, homework or not, but IMO they should be questioned if they seem dubious or self-imposed. Unfortunately "it's homework" allows valid but nonsensical constraints.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Third bullet under *"Answering and moderating homework questions"*.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Its a very nice answer. Great find friend!:) But unfortunately few people don't consider the constraints of a homework question and that makes me real sad. Specially the comment that my downvoter friend posted. Really gives out negative vibes to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your downvoter friend who posted the comment is incorrect... homework questions are perfectly acceptable here, and they should be handled *based on the constrants that are given in the question.*  Lots of programming problems come to Stack Overflow with some lame constraint imposed on them by their Pointy-Haired Boss, but we don't turn those questions away just because their PHB is clueless.

Comment: Is there a way we could let the users know that we must honour the constraint the OP has and try to post answers accordingly? We can, ofcourse, add a tip at the end asking the OP to use the easiest solution, if someday, the constraint is lifted.

Comment: Refer them to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.  Cite the third bullet in the first answer under "Answering and moderating homework questions"